# adding second parameter to URL in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to add a second parameter to the URL (and still keep the first parameter). eg I have the url /shops?sorting=alphabetically, and want to add the parameter currency=CAD

```
%form{action: shops_path(params.merge!({currency: params[:currency]}))}
    .input-group
      = select_tag 'currency', options_for_select({'USA' => 'USD' , 'Canada' => 'CAD'}, params[:currency]), class: 'select2'
```

In the code above, however, the parameter just gets replaced, eg I get /shops?currency=CAD instead of /shops?sorting=alphabetically&currency=CAD
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `hidden_field_tag` instead,

```
= form_tag shops_path do
  .input-group
    = select_tag 'currency', options_for_select({'USA' => 'USD' , 'Canada' => 'CAD'}, params[:currency]), class: 'select2'
    = hidden_field_tag :sorting, params[:sorting]
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: doesn't add the extra parameter to the URL, I see only 1 parameter

Comment: `currency` key is already there in `select_tag`, you don't need to append that with the URL.

Answer (score 0):

```
%form{action: shops_path(sorting: 'alphabetically', currency: 'CAD')}
```

No need to merge the params hash like that when supplying params to a path helper!

Comment: I've tried that as well and it gives the same result (/shops?currency=CAD)

Comment: Did you set it up in your routes file as "resources :shops"?

Comment: Sorry set what up? The route is set up and working, just doesn't add the extra param